# jQuery Autocomplete change event not capturing ui.item when user clicks away

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Trying to use jQuery Autocomplete. I set up the change event, which does fire when there is a value change. However, **the user-selected value (ui.item) is only captured when user tabs away from the input field**. And if the user clicks away using the mouse, then ui.item turns out to be null. I am getting the same result in both Chrome and IE. Is this a bug with the plugin or I did not set it up properly? I guess I can use a workaround in this post ([jquery ui autocomplete change event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28020466/jquery-ui-autocomplete-change-event)). But would like to see if this can be fixed properly before taking that route. Thanks very much!

```
    jQuery('#pts').autocomplete({
        source: list,
        open: function(e, ui) {
            $('.ui-autocomplete').css('top', $("ul.ui-autocomplete").cssUnit('top')[0]);
            $('.ui-autocomplete').css('left', $("ul.ui-autocomplete").cssUnit('left')[0]);
        },
        minLength: 0,
        change: function(e, ui) {
            if (ui.item) {
                fetchCs();
            } else {
                alert("user picked new value");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I ended up checking the user-selected value in the else block and comparing against the list of options. It is working fine but hopefully this issue with the plugin can be addressed.